# Magento 2 How to show Layered Navigation on home page?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, search

I want to show Layered Navigation on Home Page.

On home page their is banner slider and on banner image their is Search Box like below.

[image]

Now I want show Layered Navigation instead of that search box.

And I can remove that search box but Don't know

How to show Layered Navigation on Home Page?

Comment: I have tried your code block in home page and it works finely. But it shows only price list as in the figure. Is there anyway that I can list all the subcategories in the same way ? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvfS2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvfS2.png)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/126799)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/126799)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show layered navigation on home page do following->

Edit  CMS homepage, inside it in design tab -> layout -> selected "2 columns with left bar".
Then added following code in design-> Layout Update XML

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="layer/view.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Then cleared cache.

[image]

Comment: What will be condition if want layered navigation for particular category ID ? I was able to get in Magento 1 but not in Magento 2

Comment: @Abhishek You need to add category filter for advanced search and then pass your category_id as parameter in url (hidden variable) then it will show layered navigation for that specific category.
To add category filter you can refer this <https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176502/magento-2-how-to-add-search-by-category-in-advanced-search>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want this on custom page. Suppose I want all filter attribute of category id 10 on "about us" page left side bar.

Comment: @Abhishek Have you got any solution? If no then plz post new question with your requirements?

Comment: I have already posted ..  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172674/magento-2-layered-navigation-on-cms-page-or-homepage-with-selected-category