# magento 2 layered navigation on CMS page or homepage with selected category

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, cms-pages

I want layered navigation on CMS page with selected cateogry. I am following [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169812/magento-2-how-to-show-layered-navigation-on-home-page/170036#170036)

It is showing all category and attribute. But I don't know how to set selected category. For example on Clothing CMS page want to show attributes of  Shirt category in layered navigation.

Answer (score 2):

This link might help you: https://swissuplabs.com/blog/practical-guide-magento-and-magento-2-layered-navigation/

XML to show layered navigation on home:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
    <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="layer/view.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

XML to show products:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
        <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                   name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        </block>
        <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to add attribute selection via layout update as well?
I only found the category filter, but not for the attributes

```
<arguments>
        <argument name="category_id" xsi:type="string">83</argument>
</arguments>
```