# Magento 2 Import images for SKUs from external resource

Tags: magento-2.1, import, product-images, external-images

I am importing images from third party url and following [Magento 2 guideline](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html)

But It is throwing errors for some rows but others are imported successfully while I can access images for particular error row directly.
[image]

Comment: Abhishek, may be your external resource does not give permission to  dowload image files

Comment: or you may be  have request time out issue,please try with single record.

Comment: Thanks @AmitBera .. It follow your instructions. it works form me !!!

Comment: Hi @AmitBera... can you you look at this question.. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172674/magento-2-layered-navigation-on-homepage-with-selected-category