# Magento 2 : Add Search by Category in Advanced search

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category-attribute, advanced-search

I tried the code of @Nitesh here [Add search by category by Nitesh](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176502/magento-2-how-to-add-search-by-category-in-advanced-search/)

and I got this error:

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced::$_objectManager in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/mwh-das-original/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Advanced.php
>   on line 269

[image]

and also notice that category list doubled 
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 : How To Add Search By Category In Advanced Search?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176502/magento-2-how-to-add-search-by-category-in-advanced-search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is error in the @Nitesh code, because the `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced` class has no attribute `_objectManager`. To make it work you should add this attribute in a class which rewrites `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced`, I think you have it because @Nitesh says:

> To add this, you will need to override the following files:
>
> ```
> vendor/magento/core/module-catalog-search/Block/Advanced/Form.php
> vendor/magento/core/module-catalog-search/Model/Advanced.php
> vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/form.phtml
> ```

So, just declare the `__construct` method and add the `ObjectManager` instance and attribute, like:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory as AttributeCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Advanced\Collection as ProductCollection;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\AdvancedFactory;
use Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute as EntityAttribute;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class YourRewriteAdvancedClassName extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory
     * @param Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param Config $catalogConfig
     * @param CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     * @param ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param AdvancedFactory $advancedFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
        Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        Config $catalogConfig,
        CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        AdvancedFactory $advancedFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $attributeCollectionFactory,
            $catalogProductVisibility,
            $catalogConfig,
            $currencyFactory,
            $productFactory,
            $storeManager,
            $productCollectionFactory,
            $advancedFactory,
            $data
        );
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    // Here is you custom method from question
}
```

**PS:** update the class which rewrites `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced` class using this code, but do not overwrite it completely.

Comment: @JeraldLaxamana I'm glad to help you.

Comment: hi @Siarhey one last thing. can you help to override the Form.php?
i created module and the Advanced.php is working. but when i try to override Form.php advanced search page is blank.

Comment: @JeraldLaxamana Sure, but please ask another question and add full code (or link on github)

Comment: hi @Siarhey you can check https://github.com/nihachi/AddSearchByCategory . sorry im newbie creating module also in backend.

Comment: @JeraldLaxamana Ok, I’ll see how i can help you when i’ll have free time.

Answer (score 0):

Although its not good to use object manager but if you want to you need to initiate it before.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Advanced\Collection');
```