# How To Add Search By Category In Advanced Search in magento 2.3?

Tags: category, magento2.3, catalogsearch, advanced-search

How To Add Search By Category In Advanced Search in magento 2.3 ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176502/magento-2-how-to-add-search-by-category-in-advanced-search

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178995/magento-2-add-search-by-category-in-advanced-search

Comment: When I apply this solution the error is showing due to form.phtml. Can you give me correct code?