# Magento 2 : To show category with in the top search bar results

Tags: category, search, catalogsearch, search-criteria

How to show categories on the top search bar results?

Do not want to interact with ElasticSearch as using MySQL search engine.

Any sort of note would be much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176563/72911)

To add this, you will need to override the following files:

```
vendor/magento/core/module-catalog-search/Block/Advanced/Form.php
vendor/magento/core/module-catalog-search/Model/Advanced.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/form.phtml
```

At below code in Form.php, add:

```
protected $_categoryHelper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
) {
    $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
  }
```

Add below function in Form.php:

```
public function getStoreCategories()
{
   return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories();
}
```

In Advanced.php, replace the getSearchCriterias() function with the code below:

```
public function getSearchCriterias()
{
    $search = $this->_searchCriterias;
    /* display category filtering criteria */
    if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])) {
        $category = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($_GET['cat']);
        $search[] = array('name'=>'cat','value'=>$category->getName());
    }
    return $search;
}
```

replace getProductCollection() function,  with:

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
        $this->_productCollection = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Advanced\Collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addStoreFilter();
        /* need to include product active and visibility filtering here*/    
        /* include category filtering */
        if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])) $this->_productCollection->addCategoryFilter($this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($_GET['cat']),true);
    }

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Now search this function addFilters. In this function you can see following condition code,

```
if ($allConditions)
```

replace above with following code:

```
if ($allConditions || (isset($values['cat']) && is_numeric($values['cat'])) )
```

In form.phtml, after `endforeach` line i.e. line no 122 add below code:

```
   <li>
        <label for="category_search_field">Search by Category:</label>
        <select name="cat" id="category_search_field">
            <option value="">-- Any Category --</option>
            <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>

            <?php if($_category->hasChildren()): ?>
                  <option class="parent-cat" value="<?php echo $_category->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName();?></option>
              <?php if($_category->getIsActive()) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $_category->getId(); ?>"<?php echo ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('cat') == $_category->getId() ? ' selected="selected"': "") ?>><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></option>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php elseif($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_category->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName();?></option>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>

        </select>
    </li>
```

(Above code will show 1st level categories.)

Now You can see category filter in Advanced Search.