# Magento 2 How to show multiple Or category wise Layered Navigation on home page?

Tags: magento2, category, magento2.2, layered-navigation, home-page

I want to show multiple Layered Navigation on Home Page.

I want to show multiple Layered Navigation category wise on Home Page.

I refer this [Magento 2 How to show Layered Navigation on home page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169812/magento-2-how-to-show-layered-navigation-on-home-page) article.

Comment: Try adding the blocks in <referenceContainer name="main.contents">

Comment: Try: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169812/magento-2-how-to-show-layered-navigation-on-home-page

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but i refer your link and it's for only one type of layer navigation. there are no way for category wise... i hope you understand...

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Cms Page > Homeopage >  design tab -> layout -> selected "2 columns with left"`, Then 
See **Design** Tab.

**Now You can add:-**

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="layer/view.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
        </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

**This Will Works :-)**