# Layered navigation only for subcategories in home page

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, search, catalogsearch, category-listing

I have these sub-categories under books category.

[image]

I have tried adding this code to my home page as described in here [Magento 2 How to show Layered Navigation on home page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169812/magento-2-how-to-show-layered-navigation-on-home-page) . But it shows only price.

I need to show these subcategories in the home page as a list and navigate to the relevant books when clicking on it. 
How can I do this by customizing the CMS rather doing code modifications ?

Comment: did you set categories , is_anchor = Yes ?

Comment: Yes. In 'Books" page it shows the layered navigation pane under categories. What I need is, displaying all the subcategories in the home page.