# Magento2 : How to add layered navigation in CMS Home page?

Tags: layered-navigation, home-page, magento2.2.4

I need to add layered navigation on my home page. It is available on other pages but not in Homepage. I have tried this one too -> [Magento 2 How to show Layered Navigation on home page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169812/magento-2-how-to-show-layered-navigation-on-home-page) , but it is not working for me.

How to add this to the homepage?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169812/magento-2-how-to-show-layered-navigation-on-home-page

Comment: i tried this. but not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml` with such content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body> 
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="layer/view.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not working. Do you have any idea?